# Why does this numpy multinominal method run without any error?

Tags: python, statistics, probability

I ran the following line:

```
np.random.multinomial(10, [1/5., 1/5., 1/5., 1/5., 1/5., 1/5.])
```

and it produces an output

```
array([3, 4, 0, 0, 3, 0])
```

which means that when I roll a 6 sided dice for 10 times, the above output represents the frequency counts of number of times a particular side showed up. Here, side 1 showed up 3 times, side 2 showed up 4 times and so on.

My question is shouldn't the above method throw an error because the probability values of the sides of the dices sum to > 1/0 ? I am sure I have misunderstood something here but not able to figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says:

```
pvals : sequence of floats, length p
    Probabilities of each of the ``p`` different outcomes.  These
    should sum to 1 (however, the last element is always assumed to
    account for the remaining probability, as long as
    ``sum(pvals[:-1]) <= 1)``.
```

That means that the last element is assigned a probability of 0
Run this:

```
sum_last = 0

for trial in np.arange(20):
    sum_last += np.random.multinomial(10, [1/5., 1/5., 1/5., 1/5., 1/5., 1/5.])[-1]
print sum_last
```

You'll see how the last element never shows up, the probability is indeed 0

Answer (score 1):

actually code will consider only till the pvals sums to 1. so in this case only the first five sums. so in you array 6th element will be zero no matter how many times you run. so incase you give 1/3 for all 6 elements then, it will execute as if a dice of side 3 is thrown and in the output array last 3 elements will be zero. It does not have to show error. It will stop once the sum reaches one and simply neglect others. that is the syntax.
Hope this helps.